# im facing error in laravel stripe payment integration using custom page ajax in laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-10

"A `return_url` must be specified because this Payment Intent is configured to automatically accept the payment methods enabled in the Dashboard, some of which may require a full page redirect to succeed. If you do not want to accept redirect-based payment methods, set `automatic_payment_methods[enabled]` to `true` and `automatic_payment_methods[allow_redirects]` to `never` when creating Setup Intents and Payment Intents."
im facing this error for first time while integration of stripe payment gateway in laravel using api custom page ajax

here is my checkout controller code

```
  $user = Auth::user();
  $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
  $intent = $user->createSetupIntent();
  return view('website.checkout.index', compact('data', 'intent'));
```

and my order placed controller code is

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
$paymentMethod = $request->input('paymentMethod');
$user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);      
 try {
   $response = $user->charge($request->input('grand_total') * 100, $paymentMethod, [
   'currency' => 'USD',
   'confirmation_method' => 'manual',                   
   ]);
   if ($response->id) {
   // Store the payment method in session so we can use it later.  

    }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
    return response()->json($exception->getMessage());
   }
```

i want to find the solution of this error if you know than plese tell me why this error occuring again and again

Comment: The error message already explains what to do `If you do not want to accept redirect-based payment methods, set automatic_payment_methods[enabled] to true and automatic_payment_methods[allow_redirects] to never` - is there a reason why you're not following what the error message recommends?

Comment: but problem is that i don't know where it is right i right in controller but it give me error

Comment: nothing in the code snippets you've shared show how you're including those parameters. If you've tried those suggestions mentioned by the error message, you'll want to update your code to reflect that so that we can advise on next steps